# Why does changing debug to 0 in CakePHP break static Pages?

Tags: cakephp

Everything was working fine. No errors. I change debug to 0, and all of the sudden my pages are giving 404 errors, and in my logs I'm noticing that variables I declared in my app controller (that were working perfectly before) are now coming back as not defined.

Weirdness. Why would changing debug to 0 cause this kind of behaviour?

**Edit: Apr 18, 2012**

I poked around the Pages controller. After the "$path = func_get_args();"  when I threw in a die(print_r($path)). With debug 1 or 2 it returns this on my home page:

```
Array
(
    [0] => home
)
```

It's blank when debug is set to 0.

Here's some of my routing:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));

Router::connect('/today', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'today'));
Router::connect('/profile', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));

$staticPages = array(
        'about',
        'contact'
);

$staticList = implode('|', $staticPages);

Router::connect('/:static', array(
    'plugin' => false,
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'display'), array(
        'static' => $staticList,
        'pass' => array('static')
    )
);
```

From the debug log:

```
2012-04-17 10:28:08 Notice: Notice (8): Undefined variable: loggedIn in [/Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/app/View/Elements/Header.ctp, line 3]
Trace:
include - APP/View/Elements/Header.ctp, line 3
View::_evaluate() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 908
View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 872
View::element() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 412
include - APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp, line 22
View::_evaluate() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 908
View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 872
View::renderLayout() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 527
View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 471
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 959
ExceptionRenderer::_outputMessage() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 263
ExceptionRenderer::error400() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 209
ExceptionRenderer::render() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 165
ErrorHandler::handleException() - CORE/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 127
[main] - [internal], line ??
```

Error log:

```
2012-04-17 10:28:08 Error: [NotFoundException] Not Found
#0 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/lib/Cake/View/View.php(908): include()
#1 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/lib/Cake/View/View.php(872): View->_evaluate('/Users/conrad/D...', Array)
#2 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/lib/Cake/View/View.php(463): View->_render('/Users/conrad/D...')
#3 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(959): View->render('about', NULL)
#4 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/app/Controller/PagesController.php(88): Controller->render('about')
#5 [internal function]: PagesController->display('about')
#6 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(485): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(PagesController), Array)
#7 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(103): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#8 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(85): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(PagesController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#9 /Users/conrad/Desktop/Creative/DEV/virtutrain/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#10 {main}
```

Again... not getting any errors whatsoever when debug is at 1 or 2...

This installation is being run locally on MAMP, but the errors also occur on the published site which is running on MediaTemple's grid service (with more or less default settings).

Comment: Never had or seen this problem before. Could you provide more information? Routing configuration, core settings, server configuration, etc.

Comment: The error you traced shows that `$loggedIn` doesn't exist, but that's because it was generating a 404 error (because the controller/action wasn't probably wasn'found) and probably skipped your code that sets the variable. Turn debug off and go to the same url, the exception/error should be more specific.

Comment: That's the thing; when I turn debug on, there are absolutely no errors thrown or logged whatsoever, and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Could caching have something to do with it? Caching is off when debug > 0. Try manually clearing the app/temp folder contents.

Comment: Cleared the cache, no change.

Answer (score 3):

Wow... this was sitting in my home.ctp Page view, and got copied to all other pages:

```
if (Configure::read('debug') == 0):
    throw new NotFoundException();
endif;
```

Major wtf, but regardless... problem solved.

Comment: The reason why the exception is thrown with debug turned off is [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4109#issuecomment-50524943). (Added this comment to help those reaching here by searching.)