# CakePHP empty error in error log

Tags: cakephp, error-log

We have a website that everytime you go to the home page, gets an empty error logged in the error log.

```
2015-01-26 14:52:27 Error: [NotFoundException] Not Found
Request URL: /
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/lib/Cake/View/View.php(948): include()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/lib/Cake/View/View.php(910): View->_evaluate('/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/lib/Cake/View/View.php(471): View->_render('/var/www/vhosts...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(954): View->render('home', NULL)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/app/Controller/PagesController.php(41): Controller->render('home')
#5 [internal function]: PagesController->display('home')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(490): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(PagesController), Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(191): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(165): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(PagesController), Object(CakeRequest))
#9 /var/www/vhosts/.nl/subdomains//httpdocs/app/webroot/index.php(108): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#10 {main}
```

I have no idea what causes this error. I tried deleting the whole file so you only see a blank page, but then the error still logs. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT to answer some questions: 
We have two layouts. One normal default.ctp and a home.ctp, the home page only has the layout/home.ctp, no pages/home.ctp.

Comment: What is the default page which should be shown here? Maybe it tries to show something and is missing a parameter or looking for an id which doesn't exist.
Do you start with a static page or a view fro a controller?

Comment: View->render('home', NULL)  What is home? And is it ok for home to have NULL there?

Comment: **https://github.com/cakephp/app/issues/43** | **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192997/why-does-changing-debug-to-0-in-cakephp-break-static-pages**

Comment: I updated my questions to answer the 'home' question. But I also looked at the links from ndm. After that I added in the "View" map the "Pages/home.ctp" file (didn't have it, see my updated question) and that solved the problem it looks like! So ndm if you want you can you answer my question with that, then I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my project missed the "Views/Pages/home.ctp" file. The website has two Layouts, home.ctp and default.ctp (for the rest of the pages). Because we didn't have anything in "Views/Pages/home.ctp" we deleted the file, but because of that we got the error. When we put back the file (with nothing in it) the error went away.

If you want to read more of the problem, look at the links **ndm** provided, the solved my question!