# CakePHP 3 The requested address '/' was not found on this server when debug = false

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I created a web application in CakePHP 3 and everything works find when I have `debug = true`. When I set `debug = false`, I am unable to access the base URL and get the message below.

> Not Found
>
> Error: The requested address '/' was not found on this server.

I checked my route file and it was still pointing /Pages/display with the code below.

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
```

The template for `src/Template/Pages/home.ctp` exists so I am totally clueless at this point why it won't work when debug is disabled.

I went as far as creating a new CakePHP 3 site with composer then disabling debug but get the same issue.

I looking into my error log and found this.

```
2016-02-03 09:53:11 Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException] Not Found
Request URL: /
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/printsling/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(992): include()
#1 /var/www/html/printsling/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(952): Cake\View\View->_evaluate('/var/www/html/p...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/printsling/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(587): Cake\View\View->_render('/var/www/html/p...')
#3 /var/www/html/printsling/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(612): Cake\View\View->render('home', NULL)
#4 /var/www/html/printsling/src/Controller/PagesController.php(66): Cake\Controller\Controller->render('home')
#5 [internal function]: App\Controller\PagesController->display('home')
#6 /var/www/html/printsling/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(430): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/printsling/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(114): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#8 /var/www/html/printsling/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\PagesController))
#9 /var/www/html/printsling/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#10 {main}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here.
[Why does changing debug to 0 in CakePHP break static Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192997/why-does-changing-debug-to-0-in-cakephp-break-static-pages)

Even though I gutted the home.ctp file to remove all information which could cause a security risk, there are 3 lines close to the top of the file which checks if the application is in debug mode and throws an error if `true`.

The following 3 lines were remove.

```
if (!Configure::read('debug')):
    throw new NotFoundException();
endif;
```